# Scaled Layers in GDI

Tags: c, windows, bitmap, codeblocks, gdi

*Original question*

> Basically, I have two bitmaps, and I want to put one behind the other, scaled down to half its size.
>   Both are centered, and are of the same resolution. 
>   The catch is that I want to put more than one bitmap on this back layer eventually, and want the scaling to apply to the whole layer and not just the individual bitmap.
>   My thought is I would use a memory DC for the back layer, capture its contents into a bitmap of its own and use StretchBlt to place it in my main dc
>   The code I have right now doesn't work, and I can't make sense of it, let alone find anyone who had done this before for direction.
>
> My variables at the moment are as follows
>
> hBitmap - back bitmap
>
> hFiller - front bitmap
>
> hdc - main DC
>
> ldc - back DC(made with CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);)
>
> resh - width of hdc
>
> resv - height of hdc
>
> **note that my viewport origin is set to the center**
>   --this part above is solved, with the one major issue being that it does not keep the back layers...

***Revised Question***

Here's my code. Everything works as intended except for the fact that the layers do not properly stack. They seem to erase what is underneath or fill it with black.

**For the record this is a direct copy of my code. I explain sections of it but there is nothing missing between the code blocks.**

```
case WM_TIMER:
            {
                switch(wParam)
                {
                case FRAME:
```

If any position or rotation values have changed, the following section of code clears the screen and prepares it to be rewritten

```
                    if(reload == TRUE){
                        tdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                        oldFiller = SelectObject(tdc,hFiller);
                        GetObject(hFiller, sizeof(filler), &filler);
                        StretchBlt(hdc, 0-(resh/2), 0-(resv/2), resh, resv, tdc, 0, 0, 1, 1, SRCCOPY);
                        SelectObject(tdc,oldFiller);
                        DeleteDC(tdc);
                        if(turn == TRUE){
                            xForm.eM11 = (FLOAT) cos(r/angleratio);
                            xForm.eM12 = (FLOAT) sin(r/angleratio);
                            xForm.eM21 = (FLOAT) -sin(r/angleratio);
                            xForm.eM22 = (FLOAT) cos(r/angleratio);
                            xForm.eDx  = (FLOAT) 0.0;
                            xForm.eDy  = (FLOAT) 0.0;
                            SetWorldTransform(hdc, &xForm);
                        }
```

This is the part that only partially works. At a distance of 80 my scale value will make my bitmap 1 pixel by 1 pixel, so I consider this my "draw distance"

It scales properly, but the layers do not stack, as I mentioned above

```
                        for(int i=80;i>1;i--){
                            tdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                            tbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, resh, resv);
                            SelectObject(tdc, tbm);
                            BitBlt(tdc, 0-(resh/2), 0-(resv/2), resh, resv,hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
                            //drawing code goes in here
                            ldc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                            oldBitmap = SelectObject(ldc,hBitmap);
                            StretchBlt(tdc,(int)(angleratio*atan((double)128/(double)i)),0,(int)(angleratio*atan((double)128/(double)i)),(int)(angleratio*atan((double)128/(double)i)),ldc,0,0,128,128,SRCCOPY);
                            SelectObject(ldc,oldBitmap);
                            DeleteDC(ldc);
                            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, resh, resv, tdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                            DeleteObject(tbm);
                            DeleteDC(tdc);
                        }
                        reload = FALSE;
                    }
```

This section below just checks for keyboard input which changes the position or rotation of the "camera"
This part works fine and can be ignored

```
                    if(GetKeyboardState(NULL)==TRUE){
                        reload = TRUE;
                        if(GetKeyState(VK_UP)<0){
                            fb--;
                        }
                        if(GetKeyState(VK_DOWN)<0){
                            fb++;
                        }
                        if(GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT)<0){
                            lr--;
                        }
                        if(GetKeyState(VK_LEFT)<0){
                            lr++;
                        }
                        if(GetKeyState(0x57)<0){
                            p++;
                        }
                        if(GetKeyState(0x53)<0){
                            p--;
                        }
                    }

                break;
              }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You could improve this question by providing a snippet of the relevant part of the code and by being more specific about "doesn't work" (perhaps by including a screenshot).  Were you able to get all of the basics to work before you tried layering?  Can you draw a bitmap?  Can you draw a bitmap to a memory DC and then display it?  Can you draw a scaled bitmap to a memory DC and then display it?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I have revised my question and provided my rendering code, explaining each section of it. I hope this helps.